# How to apply css on checkbox when it's getting disabled?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two chech Boxes (one of them disabled). I have replaced the check boxes with a div with background color with toggle function so that checked = green, unchecked = red.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input_class_checkbox" disabled="disabled">    
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="input_class_checkbox">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.input_class_checkbox').each(function(){
$(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox" />');

});

$('.class_checkbox').on('click',function(){
$(this).toggleClass('checked').prev().prop('checked',$(this).is('.checked'))
});
```

**CSS**

```
.class_checkbox {
width: 20px;  
height: 20px;
background-color: red;
}

.class_checkbox.checked {
  background-color: green;
}

 .class_checkbox.disabled {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

How do I apply this `.disabled` CSS on the disabled check box on page load? also check boxes can be disabled programmatically, so can I implement `onDisabled` kind of Jquery code to change the appearance when a check box is disabled?

Comment: You're kind of overthinking it.  Just toggle between two classes.  Something like "checkbox_enabled" and "checkbox_disabled," rather than try to coax an HTML attribute into doing something it wasn't exactly designed to do.

Comment: just select all things that are classed so $('.disabled').css( ....

Comment: @thisOneGuy except the OP hasn't really created a disabled class.  He's trying to hang this functionality off the disabled HTML attribute.

Comment: And for a more practical JQ code example, maybe something like:

Comment: BuggyCoder, do you have two states here, or three?  Looks like you're going for red, green, and blue.

Comment: If you can avoid it, note that Javascript is an unnecessary approach for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
$( "input:disabled" ).next().css( "background-color", "yellow" );
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpmv78ah/)

Answer (score 1):

### Dont use Javascript*

You should ideally look to use HTML and CSS for this, without reliance on Javascript. This ensures correct separation of concerns (HTML = content, CSS = styling, JS = functionality). It is also a cleaner more performant solution.

```css
input+span {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked +span {
  background: lightgreen;
}
input:disabled + span {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span></span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled />
  <span></span>
</label>
```

*Unless unavoidable

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `:disabled`

Something like:

```
 .input_class_checkbox:disabled {
  background-color: blue;
}
```